# insert bash variable into perl search and replace

Tags: bash

in my bash script i look for text inside a file and replace it with a variable from my bash script.  I couldn't get the variable to be recognized by the perl command.  any ideas?

mybash.bash:

```
#! /bin/sh
let "myNum=2"# myNum could be any integer
perl -pi -e 's/ABCD\d/ABCD$myNum/g' ./textfile.txt
```

textfile.txt:

'ABCD0' gets replace with 'ABCD' with above script

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use double quotes so as to enable interpolation of variables:

```
perl -pi -e "s/ABCD\d/ABCD$myNum/g" ./textfile.txt
           ^^^                   ^^^
```

Comment: "interpolate": to introduce by insertion

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using $($myNum) ? Bash needs to be able to execute/evaluate the variable?

Also, single quotes print literal fields usually and double evaluate things, so you might need to fiddle with that if the above doesn't work